# PhantomJS - wrong language in Google Analytics (Accept-Language)

Tags: google-analytics, http-headers, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I'm running some tests with PhantomJS / CasperJS on Ubuntu and Google Analytics, and i'm having problems with GA to correctly recognize my language settings that i'm sending in HTTP Request Headers.

**No matter** what i enter in my Accept-Language header, i end up with GA classifying the language as "c".

[image]

I'm sure my Accept-Language headers are correct, here's an example:

```
ACCEPT-ENCODING:gzip, deflate
CONNECTION:Keep-Alive
ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en-US
USER-AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

After long hours of trial-and-error i found out that C was in fact the default setting for the LANG env variable inside Ubuntu itself:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I can in fact impact Google Analytics classification by altering my ENV variables by using the following command from the command line:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

It does not work if i only set "export LC_LANG" or "LANGUAGE". I am not sure why either.

But **how do i control this setting from inside PhantomJS / CasperJS?** I can't / don't want to have to change my ENV variables for each PhantomJS run from CLI, i test multiple languages at once in big numbers.

Has anyone experienced this and can help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a hack-ish solution to this problem. I simply use the following command fromt he CLI:

```
$ LC_ALL=en-gb phantomjs script.js
```

and that passes the Accept-Language correctly to Google Analytics.

I think there's a problem with CasperJS request-headers being correctly passed on to PhantomJS.